# Java 8 List<String[]> to List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to read the following csv file:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

I'm using java 8 and I'm stuck at the conversion from 
`List<String[]>` to `List<List<Integer>>`:

```
Files.lines(filePath)
    .map(line -> line.split(","))
          //Here 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to map using an inner stream:

```
Files.lines(filePath)
    .map(line -> line.split(","))
    .map(array -> Arrays.stream(array).map(Integer::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why two `map` steps? Why not `.map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()))`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second possibility is working as well. @Holger Is it more performant in your opinion to do in this way or is it just more elegant?

Comment: @NikNik the difference will be tiny, if any. Not enough to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with

```
    List<String> list = Files.lines(path)
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
           ;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. It's not exactly what I was looking for as I'm trying to convert from List<String[]> to List<List<Integer>>